# Can't sign msi file with vialid certificate

Tags: .net, powershell, certificate, windows-installer, sign

I have a `.cert` and `.pfx` files. I can sign any PowerShell script or `.exe` file. When I check it with

```
signtool.exe verify /v /pa $TargetFilePath
```

It says that it is valid. But when I am trying to sign the `.msi` file it actually adds signature but verifies command returns

```
SignTool Error: WinVerifyTrust returned error: 0x80096010
        The digital signature of the object did not verify
```

Comment: Cert path issue?

Comment: @alexzelaya Could you please clarify?

Comment: Is the certification path of the cert valid? Self-signed certs usually don't have a valid certification path as they have not been emitted by a valid certificate authority.